# ruby on rails showing landing page differently from localhost and html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm implementing a landing page for a website I'm working on and found a great template online. I loaded everything up and correctly set the file links and everything. When I go into my views folder and double click the html file, it loads and looks great with all of the css and js working perfectly. The problem is that whenever I start the brick server and run it from local host as my actual landing page it's all skewed and oddly proportioned.

Most of the files loaded are from external sources, aka loaded from online vs locally, and the only two files loaded locally are referenced directly. Below is my code taken directly from my file.

Here is the landing page I am trying to implement. 
http://startbootstrap.com/grayscale.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Grayscale - Free One Page Theme for Bootstrap 3</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Fonts -->
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Custom Theme CSS -->
<link href="../../assets/stylesheets/grayscale.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-custom">

<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">
                <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>  <span class="light">Start</span> Bootstrap
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#download">Download</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<section class="intro">
    <div class="intro-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h1 class="brand-heading">Grayscale</h1>
                    <p class="intro-text">A free, premium quality, responsive one page Bootstrap theme created by Start Bootstrap.</p>
                    <div class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="about" class="container content-section text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <h2>About Grayscale</h2>
            <p>Grayscale is a premium quality, free Bootstrap 3 theme created by Start Bootstrap. It can be yours right now, all you need to do is download the template on the preview page. You can use this template for any purpose, personal or commercial.</p>
            <p>This striking, black and white theme features stock photographs by <a href="http://gratisography.com/">Gratisography</a> along with a custom Google Map skin courtesy of <a href="http://snazzymaps.com/">Snazzy Maps</a>.</p>
            <p>With this template, just the slightest splash of color can make a huge impact on the overall presentation and design.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="download" class="content-section text-center">
    <div class="download-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <h2>Download Grayscale</h2>
                <p>You can download Grayscale for free on the download page at Start Bootstrap. You can also get the source code directly from GitHub if you prefer. Additionally, Grayscale is the first Start Bootstrap theme to come with a LESS file for easy color customization!</p>
                <a href="http://startbootstrap.com/grayscale" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Visit Download Page</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="contact" class="container content-section text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <h2>Contact Start Bootstrap</h2>
            <p>Feel free to email us to provide some feedback on our templates, give us suggestions for new templates and themes, or to just say hello!</p>
            <p>feedback@startbootstrap.com</p>
            <ul class="list-inline banner-social-buttons">
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/SBootstrap" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Twitter</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-github fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Github</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/+Startbootstrap/posts" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Google+</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<div id="map"></div>

<!-- Core JavaScript Files -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<!-- Google Maps API Key - You will need to use your own API key to use the map feature -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCRngKslUGJTlibkQ3FkfTxj3Xss1UlZDA&sensor=false"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="../../assets/javascripts/grayscale.js"></script>
```

So, my question is about what I am doing wrong. Is it a problem with running bootstrap? Are there conflicting files? Why does it load differently using server vs just the file? I am completely baffled, but believe it has to be something simple.

If you need the files I am running, they are all in the link as a download from the bootstrap site.

Comment: It would help a lot if you post an image of what the "oddly proportioned css" looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**View**

> You mention clicking the HTML file in your `views` lets the landing page load up correctly

This is a problem, as Rails uses `layouts`, `unobtrusive CSS` and a range of other dependency-driven elements which ensure your app is as extensible as possible.

The problem you have is if the `view` loads correctly as a standalone file, it's generally a sign that the other aspects of your application will be interfering with it; typically the [Layout](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) & external CSS

--

**Layout**

A good test is to disable the layout for your particular `landing` action -

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   layout false, only: :landing
end
```

This will set your layout as `false` for your landing page. If you do this, you will be able to see whether the problems go away. If this is the case, you'll be best splitting your code up to work with your layout properly

[This Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/7-all-about-layouts) will help you considerably:

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly. I just had to go into my landing controller and put 'layout false, only: :index' and it all works. Thanks a bunch. It's going to be very helpful to turn off the layout on many of my pages in the future.

Comment: That's great! I would be careful about "turning off the layout" - Rails' standard practice is to include a layout for each view (it modularizes the app) - I would work to integrate the bootstrap view into a layout, rather than disabling the layout. You *can* use different layouts you know ;)